# Filter an address column to only show the city

Tags: database, arabic

I have a retail database in Arabic, the addresses are written in Arabic, I have found a way to turn the letters to numbers to maybe make it easier for me, however, I am struggling to filter only the city name from the columns.

The problem is that the address is very specific, they are more of directions and they are generally written in the format of ( city, street, building name, nearby landmark ) but most of the time it's only written as the city only.

Is there a way to extract only the city from all the addresses?

[image: sample data and numeric column]

Comment: Have you tried the `LIKE` operator?

Comment: If you have no idea what the city is in each record, and there is no strict format for the address that all records follow, and the data comes from humans and might even contain typos, there is only one real solution: Using a geocoding service to resolve "unclean" addresses into their parts.

Comment: If the city is *always* the first thing in the field, and there is a fixed number known delimiters, look into the string functions of your database. Find the position of the delimiter, cut a substring up to this point. It's not hard.

Comment: That being said, you have not stated the exact DB engine you are using, but that's required info.